# Why would dyadic cisgender women with facial hair be considered attractive?

Tags: creature-design, humans, humanoid, sex, hair

In my world, there is a revolution in the world of fashion: women, men, non-binary people, and genderfluid people all must have facial hair if they want to be among the elite models. To be exact, men are supposed to have a full beard, women are supposed to have mutton chops (sideburns reunited by a moustache), non-binary people are supposed to have both a goatee and a moustache, and genderfluid people are supposed to have a beard without a moustache.

Also, in my world, there are many species of humans: if among anatomically modern humans, only males tend to have facial hair, in some others, such as gnomes, magical humans/wizards, furry humans/therianthropes, and horned humans/demons, males, females, and intersexes all have facial hair, at the opposite, in others, such as marine humans/merfolk, giants, hematophagous humans/vampires, and winged humans/angels, males, females, and intersexes almost never have facial hair.

I know no real life society where women with facial hair were considered prettier than glabrous women.

So, I wonder why would dyadic cisgender women with facial hair be considered sexy.

Comment: "Emily Ratajkowski Proudly Rocks Armpit Hair in New Editorial: 'It Makes Me Feel Sexy' "

Comment: I'm confused by the implications of the second paragraph - are you saying that all merfolk, vampires, angels etc consider all of their own kind ugly because they have no facial hair and an unattainable fashion standard says that they must?  Is this "revolution in the world of fashion" just a marketing exercise by someone trying to sell impractical, quickly-waterlogged false beards to merfolk?

Comment: I tried looking up 'dyadic' in several dictionaries and a web search, but I still don't know what it means here. Paired? As having a partner?

Comment: @Cloudberry it appears to have a LGBT..etc meaning with regards to sex and gender that seemingly has no real or plausible connection to the words use in any other ordinary langauge prior to its adoption for this use .. basically it means a physically and chromosomally normal male or female .. so .. a seemingly pointless word that adds no additional meaning or understanding to a sentence it's used in that actually seems only to serve to make it less comprehensible for most 

Comment: Why did you use the word cisgender? how is this individuals sexuality in any way relevant to her visually perceived attractiveness to others, it's not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you just have to ponder "**attraction markers**". Think about how [birds select partners](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2017/09/170905125723.htm) and you can just extend that sort of thinking to every species. All birds are equally "hairy" (feathery) therefore they developed something else to be a stand-out trait: feather colors; or [nest building](https://www.odditycentral.com/animals/romantic-bowerbird-builds-intricate-structures-to-seduce-females.html).

If every gnome, male and female, has a luxurious long flowing beard, then there is probably some other key marker they look for.

What, precisely, these markers are for each species is a brainstorming exercise that I won't get into (that's your job!), but basically I think you need to ponder what these various races/cultures have decided to use as markers, and run with that. (Okay, one example, just to prime the pumps. If every gnome, male and female, has a full blown long luxurious beard, then facial hair is likely not much of a factor in attraction. Something else must have developed. Perhaps for women, it's their prowess at digging. "Oi, look at that one, she can pickaxe her way through a furlong of granite in a day! Hubba hubba!" For men, maybe it's their neat attire. "Why Mr. Bingles never once has a stray thread or popped button!" Whatever markers gnome society has, facial hair didn't become one, because they all have that.)

Answer (score 3):

### Why wouldn't bearded women be attractive?

Facial hair on human females is considered unattractive because it could be caused by some kind of hormonal imbalance that reduces fertility. If facial hair has no correlation with sexual traits in your species, then all bets are off as to what kind of beard styles might be all the rage among their fashionable ladies.

Answer (score 0):

Hourglass figures. You have probably heard "beautiful is in the eyes of the beholder "
This has been disproved.

Studies of human art depicting attractive men and women across time have concluded that the hourglass and triangle shape are a universal constant when it comes to attractiveness.

Simply put give a beard women an hourglass figure and she will be considered attractive

Cute not ugly.

Flaws on a attractive woman tend to be percieved as cute, or exotic instead of ugly.

Personality,  style

Attractiveness isn't just about looks, it's also attitude and style. Charisma can cover a lot of flaws.

Comment: If you only look at paintings of "attractive" people, then you will learn only that attractive people are attractive. Check mate.